# Searching for a menu item shortcut

Tags: xcode

In many MacOS apps, I can search a command menu item in a search field under Help > Search. Is there any shortcut to activate this field and start the search immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your System Preferences as shown below

[image]